# Учебники по PyQt4?

Tags: python, книги, pyqt4

Есть ли учебники как пользоваться PyQt4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прохоренок Н.А PyQt4. создание оконных приложений на python 3
Boudewijn Rempt - GUI Programming with Python QT Edition [2001].chm

посмотри на http://rutracker.org/   я от туда качал сборку доков по Qt4 и PyQt4..

Answer (score 1):

Думаю более приемлем вариант на русском, и как сказал "Котик" достаточно изучить Qt, например [Книга Макса Шлее](http://www.debugni.ru/index.php/qt45.html).

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку `PyQt` - это биндинг, то для понятия его особенностей достаточно общего [**референса.**](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/index.html)

*Здесь намного важнее иметь опыт работы с `Qt`, хорошие книги по теме можете посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/books)*